# what is the 'use' keyword in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, adonis.js

I am looking at this specific line of code to understand what it is or to find some documentation about it.

https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-rally/blob/c7378d2c3984bffba1049f50e771318ea447107c/app/Model/Channel.js

```
const Lucid = use('Lucid')
```

I am trying to write a test in adonisjs using mocha and it gives me the following error `"ReferenceError: use is not defined"`

Comment: This is not a standard part of Javascript or node.js.  In that particular code, it looks like something similar to `require()` that would be in some library which you do not appear to have available.

Comment: There is no `use` keyword. That is a function call - some library defines it. You don't seem to have that library loaded.

Comment: Look in the [package.json](https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-rally/blob/develop/package.json) to see the installed packages

Comment: I copied the package json from that project i linked to my project and I still cannot run a test. My model looks exactly the same as the model linked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`use()`](http://adonisjs.com/docs/3.1/ioc-container#_use_namespace_alias) function is provided by `adonis.js`.

> #### use(namespace/alias)
>
> Fetch a binding using it’s namespace or alias.

The adonis-lucid package has an example of how to create a model that looks identical to the code that you've linked in your question. [Creating a model docs](http://adonisjs.com/docs/3.1/adonis-blog-part3#_creating_database_model)

Comment: thanks for your answer. it was very hard finding documentation and vue.js seems to explain a bunch. As for why my test was throwing an error i copied the test.js from the linked repo and it seems to have resolved my issue. my guess is it has to do with starting the server?

Answer (score 2):

To complete the answer. `use()` function is provided by the [IoC Container](http://adonisjs.com/docs/3.2/ioc-container) of AdonisJs ([adonis-fold](https://github.com/poppinss/adonis-fold)).

This function will try to resolve a binding or a namespace defined in your Adonis configuration file and will then fallback to the default `require()` function to import a package if it didn't find anything.