# socket.io - of() and use() API

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

`const spgNamespace = io.of("/spg").use(verify());`

I tried to find the API `of()` and `use()` w.r.t Javascript and socket.io. I am unsuccessful.

I found this link: https://socket.io/docs/v3/namespaces/index.html
But they have not explained the use of API `of()` and `use()`.

I have learnt that `of()` function is related to promises but this link doesn't have anything related to it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

This SO thread says that `use()` function is related to `adonisJS` but my project is not using this library anywhere: [what is the 'use' keyword in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41268452/what-is-the-use-keyword-in-javascript)

In this code, `io` is the object of 'socket.io'.

`const spgNamespace = io.of("/spg").use(verify());`

Please explain what is this line doing and please point out the reference APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `of()` as in `server.of(nsp)` initializes and retrieves the given `Namespace`.

Find it here : https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-api/#server-of-nsp

The method `use()` as in `namespace.use(fn)` registers a middleware function, which is a function that gets executed for every incoming Socket.

Find it here : https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-api/#namespace-use-fn

---

Your code

```js
const spgNamespace = io.of("/spg").use(verify());
```

means, you first initialize and retrieve the namespace `/spg`, and then register a middleware function for retrieved namespace. I see 2 issues here :

- First : `.use()` does not return anything (as far as I know), so `spgNamespace` might turn out `undefined`;
- Second : you pass `verify()` as middleware. Which means you first execute `verify` function and pass the result into it as middleware. Try only passing the function without executing it like `.use(verify)` ... instead of `.use(verify())`